# What is a "cheap win"?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-3

In the player licence, there is a page with "Battle Data".  It includes win rate, playtime, rank, etc.  All of these are self-explanatory except for one category: "Cheap Wins".

What are the criteria for a win to be labeled "cheap" within the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find an authoritative source, but the consensus on the internet is that a cheap win is winning through chip or block damage.

[Source - Gamespot forum, possibly unreliable](http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/action/marvelvscapcom3/answers.html?qid=262446)

Comment: this is the correct answer. :D